# how to groupby a DataFrame by index

Tags: python, pandas

Now I have a DataFrame "df" as below:

```
In [28]: df[:100]
Out[28]: 
       distkm     modlat     modlon  reallat  reallon         time
0    9.325590  42.423024 -70.512309  42.5040 -70.5419  731800.5514
1    9.286476  42.416112 -70.519175  42.4956 -70.5539  731800.6319
0    4.456535  42.423877 -70.408784  42.4292 -70.4626  731802.0660
1    6.393979  42.405980 -70.367245  42.4297 -70.4382  731802.1556
2    7.447289  42.389719 -70.343267  42.4259 -70.4196  731802.2312
0    4.456535  42.423877 -70.408784  42.4292 -70.4626  731802.0660
1    6.393979  42.405980 -70.367245  42.4297 -70.4382  731802.1556
2    7.447289  42.389719 -70.343267  42.4259 -70.4196  731802.2312
3    7.329755  42.370420 -70.340029  42.4134 -70.4077  731802.3208
4    6.817408  42.355624 -70.337595  42.3942 -70.4021  731802.3972
0     ...
1     ...
```

I want to seperate the DataFrame by "df.index" like:

```
     distkm     modlat     modlon  reallat  reallon         time
0    9.325590  42.423024 -70.512309  42.5040 -70.5419  731800.5514
1    9.286476  42.416112 -70.519175  42.4956 -70.5539  731800.6319
     distkm    modlat     modlon   reallat  reallon         time
0    4.456535  42.423877 -70.408784  42.4292 -70.4626  731802.0660
1    6.393979  42.405980 -70.367245  42.4297 -70.4382  731802.1556
2    7.447289  42.389719 -70.343267  42.4259 -70.4196  731802.2312
     distkm    modlat     modlon   reallat  reallon         time
0    4.456535  42.423877 -70.408784  42.4292 -70.4626  731802.0660
1    6.393979  42.405980 -70.367245  42.4297 -70.4382  731802.1556
2    7.447289  42.389719 -70.343267  42.4259 -70.4196  731802.2312
3    7.329755  42.370420 -70.340029  42.4134 -70.4077  731802.3208
4    6.817408  42.355624 -70.337595  42.3942 -70.4021  731802.3972
```

and then plot these small "df" as a figure.
How can I approach that?
I tried "groupby(df.index)" but the result isn't what I want, it just makes every same index number together.

Comment: Indexes are supposed to be unique, so your DataFrame isn't really valid.  You may be able to group on it but you're likely to get errors for various other operations.  I'd suggest making a column out of that index.

Comment: I don't know anything about plotting, but after taking BrenBarn's advice to reset the index, something like `df.groupby(((df["index"] == 0)*1).cumsum())` should work to do the `groupby` side of things.

Comment: @DSM I try your command but it seems not what I want, thank you all the same:-D

Comment: @user1843099: well, when I do it -- after, as I said, `df = df.reset_index()` -- it gives me exactly your results, but maybe there's some difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[migrated from the comments]

I don't know much about plotting, but ISTM you can use `groupby` the way you want [NB: this assumes your index consists of integers, not strings -- replace `0` by `'0'` if I'm wrong]:

```
>>> grouped = df.reset_index().groupby(((df.index == 0)*1).cumsum())
>>> for n,g in grouped:
...     print g
...     
   index    distkm     modlat     modlon  reallat  reallon         time
0      0  9.325590  42.423024 -70.512309  42.5040 -70.5419  731800.5514
1      1  9.286476  42.416112 -70.519175  42.4956 -70.5539  731800.6319
   index    distkm     modlat     modlon  reallat  reallon         time
2      0  4.456535  42.423877 -70.408784  42.4292 -70.4626  731802.0660
3      1  6.393979  42.405980 -70.367245  42.4297 -70.4382  731802.1556
4      2  7.447289  42.389719 -70.343267  42.4259 -70.4196  731802.2312
   index    distkm     modlat     modlon  reallat  reallon         time
5      0  4.456535  42.423877 -70.408784  42.4292 -70.4626  731802.0660
6      1  6.393979  42.405980 -70.367245  42.4297 -70.4382  731802.1556
7      2  7.447289  42.389719 -70.343267  42.4259 -70.4196  731802.2312
8      3  7.329755  42.370420 -70.340029  42.4134 -70.4077  731802.3208
9      4  6.817408  42.355624 -70.337595  42.3942 -70.4021  731802.3972
```

and for each group we can set the index again, e.g.:

```
>>> g.set_index("index")
         distkm     modlat     modlon  reallat  reallon         time
index                                                               
0      4.456535  42.423877 -70.408784  42.4292 -70.4626  731802.0660
1      6.393979  42.405980 -70.367245  42.4297 -70.4382  731802.1556
2      7.447289  42.389719 -70.343267  42.4259 -70.4196  731802.2312
3      7.329755  42.370420 -70.340029  42.4134 -70.4077  731802.3208
4      6.817408  42.355624 -70.337595  42.3942 -70.4021  731802.3972
```